# Как сделать кнопку меняющую текст при каждом нажатии на нее?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$("#bat1").click(function() {
  $(this).val('night');
  $("div").toggleClass("night");
});
```

```css
.tema {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.night {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tema">
  <h1>body</h1>
  <p id="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <input id="bat1" type='button' value='svet'>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы после второго нажатия на кнопку, возвращался не только стиль `div`, но и текст кнопки снова становился `"svet"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```js
$("#bat1").click(function(){
  $(this).val( $(this).val() == 'svet' ? 'nigth' : 'svet' );
  $("div").toggleClass("night");
});
```

```css
.tema {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.night {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tema">
  <h1>body</h1>
  <p id="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <input id="bat1" type='button' value='svet'>
</div>
```

А вообще, имхо, правильнее было бы на светлом фоне показывать "night", а на темном "svet". Это все таки кнопка, а не лейбл. Думаю, логичнее, если она отражает, в *какое состояние перейти*, а не *текущее состояние*.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#bat1").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "svet") {
    $(this).val("night");
  } else {
    $(this).val("svet");
  }
  $("div").toggleClass("night");
});
```

```css
.tema {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.night {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tema">
  <h1>body</h1>
  <p id="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <input id="bat1" type='button' value='svet'>
</div>
```